# Android service leakage

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask, android-service

my application is running successfully but if i put my app ideal state for 3 to 5 mins, it shows unfortunately your app has stopped, in my application i used service, Asynctask concepts, you can observer below data

```
07-18 05:00:12.779: W/ActivityManager(277): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@41013b90
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d48ec8 that was originally bound here
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d48ec8 that was originally bound here
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-18 05:00:12.779: E/ActivityThread(692):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692): null
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d48ec8 that was originally bound here
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-18 05:00:12.870: E/StrictMode(692):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-18 05:00:12.879: D/dalvikvm(692): GC_CONCURRENT freed 474K, 21% free 2476K/3096K, paused 74ms+75ms, total 197ms
07-18 05:00:12.879: W/ActivityManager(277): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4111e8c8
```

help how to overcome such an errors

Answer (score 0):

unbind/unregister the service in onStop()